# "ParentView" moving up when keyboard appears on "ChildView" - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm completely new to SwiftUI. I read a lot of topics and did not find an answer. I struggling third day and finally I noticed last (I hope:)) problem, to be short:
ParentView call ChildView(sheet presentation), ChildView (it's just a chat) has navigation view, messages and textfield with button. When I tap textfield the keyboard appears - ParentView is moving up and it's quite noticeable. Appreciate any help!
My code:

```
final class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
private var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter

@Published private(set) var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
    notificationCenter = center
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

deinit {
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
    }

}

@objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    currentHeight = 0
}
```

}

and main code

```
    var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                ScrollViewReader { reader in
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 0.5) {
                        ForEach(messageData) { message in
                            ChatBubble(direction: message.isMine ? .right : .left) {
                                switch message.dataType {
                                case .text(let userMessage):
                                    Text(userMessage)
                                        .padding(.all, 10)
                                        .foregroundColor(message.isMine ? Color.white : Color.black)
                                        .background(message.isMine ? Color("15152B") : Color("D3E0F0"))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.clear).id(scrollToId) // padding from bottom
                        scroll(reader: reader)
                    }
                }
            }

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    
                    TextField("Отправить сообщение", text: $fullText)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 80)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        messageData.append(MessageData.init(isMine: true, dataType: .text(message: fullText)))
                        
                        //MARK:- reply to me
                        messageData.append(MessageData.init(isMine: false, dataType: .text(message: "reply to:" + fullText)))
                        fullText = ""
                        
                    }, label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
            
                    }).disabled(fullText.count == 0)
                    
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                .background(Color.white)
                
            }

        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        // dismissing view
                        
                    }) {
                        Image("back_arrow")
                    }.frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    
                    Image(userFoto)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    
                    Text(userName)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 18))
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            // deleting chat -> dismissing view
                            
                        }) {
                            Image("delete_chat")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        }
                    }

                    
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, alignment: .center)
            }
        })
        
        
        
    }

    
}
```